# Stata - how to create T variables that have values for each t in panel data

Tags: stata

Sorry if the title of my question is unclear, but it's hard to summarize it on one line. I have a panel data set (codes to generate it are at the bottom):

```
. xtset id year
       panel variable:  id (strongly balanced)
        time variable:  year, 1 to 3
                delta:  1 unit

. l, sep(3)

     +-----------------+
     | id   year     x |
     |-----------------|
  1. |  1      1   1.1 |
  2. |  1      2   1.2 |
  3. |  1      3   1.3 |
     |-----------------|
  4. |  2      1   2.1 |
  5. |  2      2   2.2 |
  6. |  2      3   2.3 |
     +-----------------+
```

I want to create variables `x_1`, `x_2` and `x_3`, where `x_j` has the value of `x` in `year` `j` for each `id`. I can achieve it as follows (with no elegance pursued):

```
. forv k=1/3 {
  2. capture drop tmp
  3. gen tmp = x if year==`k'
  4. by id: egen x_`k' = mean(tmp)
  5. }
(4 missing values generated)
(4 missing values generated)
(4 missing values generated)

. drop tmp

. l, sep(3)

     +-----------------------------------+
     | id   year     x   x_1   x_2   x_3 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |  1      1   1.1   1.1   1.2   1.3 |
  2. |  1      2   1.2   1.1   1.2   1.3 |
  3. |  1      3   1.3   1.1   1.2   1.3 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  4. |  2      1   2.1   2.1   2.2   2.3 |
  5. |  2      2   2.2   2.1   2.2   2.3 |
  6. |  2      3   2.3   2.1   2.2   2.3 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```

Is there a way without using a loop? I know I can write a `program` or an `ado` file (determining the variable names automatically), but I wonder if there are some builtin commands for my purpose.

The full commands are here.

```
clear all
set obs 6
gen id = floor((_n-1)/3)+1
by id, sort: gen year = _n
xtset id year
gen x = id+year/10
l, sep(3)
forv k=1/3 {
    capture drop tmp
    gen tmp = x if year==`k'
    by id: egen x_`k' = mean(tmp)
}
drop tmp
l, sep(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear, reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops are good. What I can do for you is shorten your loop:

```
clear all
set obs 6
gen id = floor((_n-1)/3)+1
by id, sort: gen year = _n
xtset id year
gen x = id+year/10
l, sep(3)

forv k=1/3 {
    by id: gen x_`k' = x[`k'] 
}

l, sep(3)
```

There is a decency assumption in there of a balanced panel. This loop makes no such assumption, but you need to loop over the observed years:

```
forv year = 1/3 {
    by id: egen X_`year' = total(x / (year == `year'))  
}
```

See also [this discussion](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055), especially Sections 9 and 10.

You may also be interested in `separate`, which avoids an explicit loop, but only gets you part of the way to where you want to be.

All that said, it's hard to believe that you need these variables at all. The mechanism of time series operators solves many problems, while tools such as `rangestat` (SSC) fill in many gaps.

Comment: great tips! thanks. I am happy with them. I need those variables for Chamberlain's random effects probit and other related procedures such as Wooldridge (2005, JAE). not sure if I can avoid generating them.

Comment: if `year` is 1990, 1995, 2000, ... instead, then only the loop using `egen` and `total` works without modification. If that's correct, @Nick Cox, would you edit your answer to add a remark for me and others, though it is implied by your "balanced panel" remark? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A late entry, but you could avoid loops if you wanted by using `reshape` and `merge`:

```
clear *
input float(id year x)
1 1 1.1
1 2 1.2
1 3 1.3
2 1 2.1
2 2 2.2
2 3 2.3
end

tempfile master
save `master'

reshape wide x, i(id) j(year)

tempfile using
save `using'

use `master', clear
merge m:1 id using `using', nogen
```

Comment: Thanks. A clever solution, nice and short. It handles unbalanced panel data and multiple variables. Needing temporary files slightly bothers me, but other than that I am happy with your suggestion too. It is perhaps fast when T is large.

Answer (score 1):

This "answer", which I post because it is too long as a comment, contains results from practices following Nick Cox's answer. All credits go to him.

Method 1: Use `egen` and `total, missing`.

```
levelsof year, local(yearlevels)
foreach v of varlist x {
    foreach year of local yearlevels {
        by id: egen `v'_`year' = total(`v' / (year==`year')), missing
    }
}
```

The `missing` option handles unbalanced panels.

Method 2: Use `separate` and then copy the values.

```
foreach v of varlist x {
    separate `v', by(year) gen(`v'_)
    local newvars = r(varlist)
    foreach w of local newvars {
        by id: egen f_`w' = total(`w'), missing
    }
    drop `newvars'
}
```

This also handles unbalanced panels, but the new variable names are `f_x_1`, etc. The first method needs the levels of `year`, while the second needs creating a set of intermediate variables. I personally slightly prefer the first. It would be wonderful if Method 2 can be shortened.